# Make JSoup Report Why HTML Is Invalid

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to clean and validate incoming HTML code to prevent XSS attacks.  It returned false from isValid() and I had to use the Eclipse debugger to navigate through the JSoup source code to find the problem.  Eventually I found out that it rejected an "a" element, because it didn't like the "rel" attribute.  Is there a way to make JSoup report to me (not to the user of the page) why the HTML is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Call `Parser.setTrackErrors` to enable error reporting, parse your HTML, then call `getErrors` to retrieve a list of [`ParseError`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html) objects.

Source: [API documentation of `Parser`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html)

Comment: I'm validating the HTML using Jsoup.isValid(bodyHtml, whitelist) with my own customized Whitelist.  How do I incorporate an instance of Parser into this?  Thanks.